# how to use single save bar on multiple input fields - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image of save bar and input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABHB0.png)

I am new to react, I have a problem I want to display a Savebar on [onChange] on a number of input fields.

When input length is greater than 0 then it will show, but I have multiple input, my problem is when I type in 2 0r 3 fields it shows multiple time, but I want to show it by conditions that, when it is already open then it cannot open again. thanks in advance.

```
const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(false);



const handelBanner = (e) => {

    if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
      setShowBanner(true) 
    }else{
      setShowBanner(false)
    }
}

return: 

  {showBanner ? (
<> save bar </>
) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save all the input value to the state. Watch all input change and do your conditional logic in useEffect. Like this:

```js
const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(false);
const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if () {  // put your condition
        setShowBanner(true);
    } else {
        setShowBanner(false)
    }
}, [input1, input2])

const handleChangeInput1 = e => setInput1(e.target.value);
const handleChangeInput2 = e => setInput2(e.target.value);
```